# The DateTime.MinValue is converted into 0001-01-01 08:05:43 in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, datetime

The server side is in C# and it returns object array list as json format. There is one field in the object model, it is DateTime type, and its value is `DateTime.MinValue`.

While in the page side, it receives `/Date(-62135596800000)/` in string. I guess this is because of the object is serialized. And in javascirpt, I try to convert it back to Date type.

```
var timeSpan = element.DateModify.replace('Date','').replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(/\//g,'');
console.log(timeSpan);
var d = new Date(parseInt(timeSpan));
console.log(d);
```

When converted to Date in javascript, its value is `0001-01-01 08:05:43`, not `0001-01-01 00:00:00`. Why is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DateTime.MinValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.minvalue?view=net-5.0#remarks) is 0001-01-01 00:00:00 ***UTC***. And that is indeed 0001-01-01 08:05:43 in your local time zone (whatever that may be, probably `Asia/Shanghai` or somewhere near that). When you `console.log` a `Date`, it displays the date in your local time zone. The `Date` *value* is correct. It's just displayed in a different format.

The extra 5 minutes and 43 seconds is because at the year AD 1, time zones have not been [standardised](http://www.webexhibits.org/daylightsaving/d.html), and the [local mean time offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time) from UTC at your location is +08:05:43.

Two simple ways to make it display the UTC time of 00:00:00 is to call `toISOString` or `toUTCString`:

```js
console.log(new Date(-62135596800000).toISOString());
console.log(new Date(-62135596800000).toUTCString());
```

Comment: Offsets before the late 1800s are pretty sketchy since there was no single datum to offset from. :-)

Comment: DateTime.MinValue is not UTC, the kind is 'unspecified'.

Comment: you can set the datetime to UTC by: 'new DateTime(DateTime.MinValue.Ticks, DateTimeKind.Utc)'

Comment: @Thiago Huh interesting, the "Remarks" section of the documentation disagrees with the date time kind for some reason. But in any case, it doesn't really matter for this question. The JSON serialiser interprets the `DateTime` as UTC and serialises it to `-62135596800000`.